# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field Population.gen

Tags: processing

I'm messing around with a tutorial and am trying to draw the variable gen

Neural Network

```
Population test;
PVector goal  = new PVector(400, 10);

void setup() {
  size(800, 800); //size of the window
  frameRate(100);//increase this to make the dots go faster
  test = new Population(1000);//create a new population with 1000 members
}


void draw() { 
  background(255);

  //draw goal
  fill(255, 0, 0);
  ellipse(goal.x, goal.y, 10, 10);

  //draw obstacle(s)
  fill(0, 0, 255);

  rect(0, 300, 600, 10);

  text(Population.gen,10,10);

  if (test.allDotsDead()) {
    //genetic algorithm
    test.calculateFitness();
    test.naturalSelection();
    test.mutateDemBabies();
  } else {
    //if any of the dots are still alive then update and then show them

    test.update();
    test.show();
  }
}
```

Population

```
class Population {
  Dot[] dots;

  float fitnessSum;
  int gen = 1;

  int bestDot = 0;//the index of the best dot in the dots[]

  int minStep = 1000;

  Population(int size) {
    dots = new Dot[size];
    for (int i = 0; i< size; i++) {
      dots[i] = new Dot();
    }
  }


  //------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
 ------------------------------------------------------
  //show all dots
  void show() {
    for (int i = 1; i< dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].show();
    }
    dots[0].show();
  }

  //------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
-------------------------------------------------------
  //update all dots 
  void update() {
    for (int i = 0; i< dots.length; i++) {
      if (dots[i].brain.step > minStep) {//if the dot has already taken more 
steps than the best dot has taken to reach the goal
        dots[i].dead = true;//then it dead
      } else {
        dots[i].update();
      }
    }
  }

  //------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
-----------------------------------------------------------
  //calculate all the fitnesses
  void calculateFitness() {
    for (int i = 0; i< dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].calculateFitness();
    }
  }


  //------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
------------------------------------------------------------
  //returns whether all the dots are either dead or have reached the goal
  boolean allDotsDead() {
    for (int i = 0; i< dots.length; i++) {
      if (!dots[i].dead && !dots[i].reachedGoal) { 
        return false;
      }
    }

    return true;
  }



  //------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
-------------------------------------------------------------

  //gets the next generation of dots
  void naturalSelection() {
    Dot[] newDots = new Dot[dots.length];//next gen
    setBestDot();
    calculateFitnessSum();

    //the champion lives on 
    newDots[0] = dots[bestDot].gimmeBaby();
    newDots[0].isBest = true;
    for (int i = 1; i< newDots.length; i++) {
      //select parent based on fitness
      Dot parent = selectParent();

      //get baby from them
      newDots[i] = parent.gimmeBaby();
    }

    dots = newDots.clone();
    gen ++;
  }


  //------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
 --------------------------------------------------------------
  //you get it
  void calculateFitnessSum() {
    fitnessSum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i< dots.length; i++) {
      fitnessSum += dots[i].fitness;
    }
  }

  //------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
-------------------------------------------------------------

  //chooses dot from the population to return randomly(considering fitness)

  //this function works by randomly choosing a value between 0 and the sum 
of all the fitnesses
  //then go through all the dots and add their fitness to a running sum and 
if that sum is greater than the random value generated that dot is chosen
  //since dots with a higher fitness function add more to the running sum 
then they have a higher chance of being chosen
  Dot selectParent() {
    float rand = random(fitnessSum);


    float runningSum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i< dots.length; i++) {
      runningSum+= dots[i].fitness;
      if (runningSum > rand) {
        return dots[i];
      }
    }

    //should never get to this point

    return null;
  }

  //------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
------------------------------------------------------------------
  //mutates all the brains of the babies
  void mutateDemBabies() {
    for (int i = 1; i< dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].brain.mutate();
    }
  }

  //------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
---------------------------------------------------------------------
  //finds the dot with the highest fitness and sets it as the best dot
  void setBestDot() {
    float max = 0;
    int maxIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i< dots.length; i++) {
      if (dots[i].fitness > max) {
        max = dots[i].fitness;
        maxIndex = i;
      }
    }

    bestDot = maxIndex;

    //if this dot reached the goal then reset the minimum number of steps it 
takes to get to the goal
    if (dots[bestDot].reachedGoal) {
      minStep = dots[bestDot].brain.step;
      println("step:", minStep);
    }
  }
}
```

Error: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field Population.gen

I believe this has to do with the variable being under Population so i need to convert it or something?

Thanks, please explain in most simple terms

Answer (score 1):

`gen` is an instance variable meaning it does not belong to the **class** *Population*, but rather **instances** of this class. As a result, there would be a different value for `gen` for each *Population* that you create.

With `test = new Population(1000);`, you create a new instance of the *Population* class. Therefore the object `test` has a `gen` variable and the class *Population* still does not.

You are encountering a problem because you are trying to access a `gen` variable belonging to the **class** *Population* (a static-reference), but `gen` only exists (as a non-static field) in **instances** of *Population* (ie. *Population* objects like `test` that you created).

---

You have two options to remedy your problem:

- Refer to the `gen` variable that belongs to your `test` object: 
  `text(test.gen,10,10);`
- Add the modifier `static` to `gen`: `static int gen = 1;`. The `gen` variable will belong to the *Population* **class** and you can reference it, as you were attempting, with `Population.gen`. However, if you create more populations, they will all share this one value, so it's probably not what you want to do.